# Some unicode arrows (❯) don't show up on

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode, ios7

I am trying to display a unicode arrow ❯ on my website.

I tried:

```
❯
&#10095;
&#x276f;
```

...all with the same results: the symbol displays fine on desktop browsers, but displays an empty square on the iPhone (iOS 7.0.4).

In fact, if I load the following page on my iPhone: [removed], then that same character appears as an empty square on the iPhone.

Any idea how to display a "❯" symbol on the iPhone?

Comment: Try a different font. Looking at this question on an iPhone shows a square instead of the arrow.

Comment: Did you fix this issue or do you still need help with it?

Comment: Google and stack overflow are amazing. I type in "unicode arrow not showing on ios safari" and here I am.

Answer (score 5):

The character U+276F simply does not belong to most fonts, and you are probably using a font that does not contain it.

By the way, it is not an arrow but HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT. Consider finding a more widely supported character for your purposes, or using an image, if you need an arrow different from the commonly available arrpws.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using the Helvetica font. If the font does not contain this character, how come the character is displayed properly on desktop browsers (Safari, Chrome)?

Comment: Because they use different fonts (including different sets of fallback fonts).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a Unicode arrow you'll get on iOS might be the "right-pointing angle bracket" character, or:

```
〉
&rang;
&#9002;
&#x232a;
U+232a
```

For reference, try going to http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/bracket on an iOS device, and see which characters display as expected, and which don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\&#x0035;` with `modules.woff`. (Range `\&#x0032;` through `\&#x0035;` for all directions.